# Binary operator expected

Tags: linux, shell

I have a simple problem with binary operator but I can't resolve it. Can anyone help me why this shell script not work:

```
set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit
if [ -e /root/mom/*.php ]; then
    find /root/mom/*.php -exec gpg --clearsign {} \;
else
    echo "Hello world"
fi
```

Comment: You probably have multiple files that match that pattern. `test` doesn't know what to do with them besides the first, which is used as the argument to `-e`. Then you'll have a similar problem with `find`...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that mess?

Comment: I would like to say if in the Folder /root/mom any files are with *.php than he should make an clear sign with all the *.php files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something for all php files in a directory, just use find:

```
find /root/mom -name "*.php" -exec gpg --clearsign {} \;
```

Note that it takes a list of *directories* to search in, not a list of plain files. There's no need to try to see if files exist before using it; it's not an error if they don't.